# Punches do more damage than sword?

Tags: a-dark-room

Is it bad that my punches do more damage than a sword (9, as opposed to 6)? Am I missing something? This is with perks, but still seems odd.

Comment: Did you obtain any perk?

Answer (score 2):

After playing this a bit more I found out that punches only count at one weapon, and you can only attack one punch at a time. More than one weapon can be used at once, allowing for more damage to be dealt in a smaller period of time.

Comment: With martial artist perk, though, punch cooldown is 1s and damage is 15 or so. That means you can deliver punches faster than you could perform attacks with a whole bunch of weapons, and each punch will deal as much damage as strongest of weapons. This requires obscene amounts of unarmed fight training though.